# KATA vs NABLA Containers Isolation

Tags: containers, virtualization, comparison

I am struggling with retrieving the difference between :

- [KATA](https://katacontainers.io/) 
  and
- [IBM NABLA](https://nabla-containers.github.io/).

Or better, what is the added value of the one over the other?

Both come with enhancement of containers isolation: something between container and VM.

But, still, the difference/added value is not clear.

**KATA** is more clear for me since I successfully ran KATA container in GCP and I wrote an [article about it](http://elegance.abdennoor.com/successfully-running-kata-containers-in-the-cloud).

I will paste here the definition of each one from its official website, it might be helpful in retrieving the difference/added value :

> Kata Containers is a new open source project building extremely
>   lightweight virtual machines that seamlessly plug into the containers
>   ecosystem.

--

> Nabla containers achieve isolation by adopting a strategy of attack
>   surface reduction to the host

Comment: The article that you wrote does not seem to exist anymore as a 404 is returned. Could you edit the Q&A?